# Summarizing data from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have 9 sheets with 1668 rows and 34 cols. The code collects all data from every sheet into one Summary sheet in the following format:

> ```
> service 1 supplier 1 price etc..
> service 1 supplier 2 price etc..
> ```

Unfortunately excel freezes around the 7k row and I receive 'out of memory' error. Any suggestions how to solve improve to code to run on large data?

```
Sub goEasy()

Dim wsText As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wSum As Worksheet
Dim service As String
Dim supplier As String
Dim priceRange As String
Dim price As String
Dim Lrow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
Set wSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

wsText = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each element In wsText
        'For i = 5 To LastRow
        a = 4
        b = 12
        Do While a < LastRow
            'For j = 13 To 47

            If a = LastRow Then
            a = 4
            Exit Do
            End If
            a = a + 1

            Do While b <= 47

            If b = 47 Then
            b = 12
            Exit Do
            End If

                b = b + 1
                Lrow = wSum.UsedRange.Rows(wSum.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1

                service = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, 1).Text
                supplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(4, b).Text
                priceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(2, 1).Text
                price = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, b).Text

                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 1) = service
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 2) = supplier
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 3) = priceRange
                wSum.Cells(Lrow, 4) = price
            'Next j
            Loop
        'Next i
        Loop
    Next element

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox ("Complete")

End Sub
```

Comment: How does it freeze at 7K rows when you have 1,668 rows per sheet? Does it run to completion with a smaller data set? It's extremely hard to follow what your code is doing, with that thrice-nested loop, the insufficient indentation, confusing or irrelevant comments and the single-letter variable names - I'd suggest you try to improve the readability first, *and then* make changes to improve performance and memory footprint. Otherwise you'll be making changes and very likely introduce bugs.

Comment: @Mat'sMug 1st loop goes through the sheets. The second loop gets each row and the 3rd loop appends all the supplier + price... to the line. It just freezes after a few minutes and after closing I receive out of memory error. The single word variables are just iterators.

Comment: Can you show how the data looks?  Is in tabular format with rows and column headers? I have a solution that will use no loops but I need to see how the data is laid out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Naming

In order for code to be **useful**, it has to be understood. This applies equally to you now, you in 6 months and anybody else who eventually has to work with it. As such, code should be written for other people to read and understand.

Documentation helps with this. Writing down what your program is doing/why. But the easiest way is just to name things **descriptively** and **unambiguously**.

---

```
Dim service As String
Dim supplier As String
Dim priceRange As String
Dim price As String
```

These are **good** names. Somewhat ambiguous, I'd prefer something like `serviceName, supplierName, priceText` etc. to be completely unambiguous, but I can look anywhere in your code, see those variables and know precisely what they are.

---

```
Dim wsText As Variant
Dim wSum As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long
```

These are **not** good names.

If I see something called `wsText` I'm going to parse that as `Worksheet Text` which means... some kind of text, in a worksheet? A worksheet called text? Oh, it's a **list** of worksheet **names**.

Yeah, that was completely non-obvious. 
Just call it `worksheetNames` or maybe `targetWorksheetNames`.

`wSum` is similarly ambiguous and not-obvious about what it is. Just call it `summarySheet`.

`a, b` are generic, and hence useless. Here, they refer to `Row` and `Column` indexes, so why not call them `currentRow, currentcolumn`?

---

Good naming just makes code a hell of a lot easier to work with. Like so:

```
Sub AggregateSheetData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim sheetNames As Variant
    sheetNames = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

    Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
    Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    Dim currentSummaryRow As Long
    currentSummaryRow = summarySheet.Cells(summarySheet.Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim service As String
    Dim supplier As String
    Dim priceRange As String
    Dim price As String

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim currentSheetName As String
    Dim currentRow As Long, currentColumn As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Dim sheetCounter As Long
    For sheetCounter = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)

        currentSheetName = sheetNames(sheetCounter)
        Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheetName)

        lastRow = currentSheet.Cells(currentSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For currentRow = 5 To lastRow
            currentSummaryRow = currentSummaryRow + 1

            For currentColumn = 12 To 47

                priceRange = currentSheet.Cells(2, 1).Text
                service = currentSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Text
                supplier = currentSheet.Cells(4, currentColumn).Text
                price = currentSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Text

                summarySheet.Cells(currentSummaryRow, 1) = service
                summarySheet.Cells(currentSummaryRow, 2) = supplier
                summarySheet.Cells(currentSummaryRow, 3) = priceRange
                summarySheet.Cells(currentSummaryRow, 4) = price

            Next currentColumn
        Next currentRow
    Next sheetCounter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox ("Complete")

End Sub
```

---

Now things are becoming a lot clearer, and we can move on to the next stage of making this code **useful**. Namely, explaining and documenting important information.

---

### Magic Numbers

A magic number is any hard-coded value which appears in your code.

Why does `a` start at 5?

Why does `b` only go from 12 to 47?

Why is `supplier` always pulled from row 5?

Why is `service` always pulled from column 1?

Why are they laid out in columns 1-4 of the summary sheet, and in that order?

How do we know that our worksheets haven't been renamed?

For each of these questions, you should either re-structure your code so they don't have to be hard-coded, **or** you leave a note explaining why they have the values they have and put them in appropriate variables.

In this case, I recommend **constants**. Like so:

```
'/ Each sheet is laid out with Suppliers on row 4, Service in column 1, and then price values in a grid.
Const SUPPLIER_ROW As Long = 4
Const SERVICE_COLUMN As Long = 1

...

...

For currentRow = SUPPLIER_ROW + 1 to finalRow
    For currentColumn = SERVICE_COLUMN + 1 to finalColumn

    ...

    ...
```

And now, if your data ever moves around, you only have to go and change that value in **one** place. And everywhere else in your code, you can refer to your constant **by name**, rather than trusting that you'll remember why the numbers are what they are.

---

### Arrays

This is where we're going to give you a **serious** performance tune-up. I expect it will solve all of your speed and memory problems.

Doing **anything** to a `Worksheet` is a huge operation. If you write

```
priceRange = currentSheet.Cells(2, 1).Text
```

it doesn't feel like a big operation, but you have to query the `Worksheet` Object, which queries the `Cells` object, which searches through a couple billion range objects to find the one you're after, which then gets queried to determine the `text` value it's currently displaying. This also triggers `Worksheet` Events (query handlers, events, calculations, screenUpdating, validation, etc.) which fire off their own chains of cascading events and so on and so forth.

And you're doing this roughly **2 Million** times.

*(N.B. the above is for illustration only. The actual chain of events is much more complex and convoluted).*

---

When working with **data**, what you want is an `Array`. An `Array` is just a grid of values laid out in memory, so querying a value from an `Array` is literally a **trillion** times faster than querying it from a `Worksheet` object.

VBA makes this incredibly easy. Just create a `Range` that encompasses all your data, and do the following:

```
Dim dataArray As Variant
dataArray = dataRange
```

And now, whatever was in the topLeft Cell of your Range is in `dataArray(1, 1)`. Next row down `dataArray(2, 1)` and so forth. you can then read this data back to a worksheet by doing the same in reverse:

```
pasteRange = dataArray
```

---

The following is your code, re-written to use Arrays, and it will be quite literally a thousand times faster:

```
Sub AggregateSheetData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '/ row/column positions on data sheets
    Const SUPPLIER_ROW As Long = 4
    Const SERVICE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const START_COLUMN As Long = 12

    Const SUMMARY_SHEET_NAME As String = "Summary"

    Dim sheetNames As Variant
    sheetNames = Array("<25K", "25K <100K", "100K <250K", "250K <500K", "500K <1M", "1M <5M", "5M <15M", "15M <30M", "30M <50M")

    Dim summaryData As Variant
    ReDim summaryData(1 To 4, 1 To 1)
    Dim summaryCounter As Long

    Dim service As String
    Dim supplier As String
    Dim priceRange As String
    Dim price As String

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim sheetData As Variant
    Dim finalRow As Long, finalColumn As Long
    Dim iRow As Long, iColumn As Long

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim currentSheetName As String

    Dim sheetCounter As Long
    For sheetCounter = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)

        currentSheetName = sheetNames(sheetCounter)
        Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheetName)

        With currentSheet

            priceRange = .Cells(2, 1).Text

            finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SERVICE_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
            finalColumn = .Cells(SUPPLIER_ROW, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            Set dataRange = .Range(.Cells(SUPPLIER_ROW, SERVICE_COLUMN), .Cells(finalRow, finalColumn))

        End With

        sheetData = dataRange

        Dim LB1 As Long, UB1 As Long
        Dim LB2 As Long, UB2 As Long
        LB1 = LBound(sheetData, 1)
        UB1 = UBound(sheetData, 1)
        LB2 = LBound(sheetData, 2)
        UB2 = UBound(sheetData, 2)

        For iRow = LB1 To UB1
            service = sheetData(iRow, LB2)

            For iColumn = (START_COLUMN - SERVICE_COLUMN + 1) To UB2

                supplier = sheetData(LB1, iColumn)
                price = sheetData(iRow, iColumn)

                summaryCounter = summaryCounter + 1
                ReDim Preserve summaryData(1 To 4, 1 To summaryCounter)

                summaryData(1, summaryCounter) = service
                summaryData(2, summaryCounter) = supplier
                summaryData(3, summaryCounter) = priceRange
                summaryData(4, summaryCounter) = price

            Next iColumn
        Next iRow
    Next sheetCounter

    Dim summarySheet As Workbook
    Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SUMMARY_SHEET_NAME)

    Dim pasteRange As Range
    With summarySheet

        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set pasteRange = .Range(.Cells(finalRow + 1, 1), .Cells(finalRow + summaryCounter, 4))
        pasteRange = summaryData

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox ("Complete")

End Sub
```

Comment: Will it be literally 3 million times faster or literally 1000 times faster? ;) Solid answer and explanation.

Comment: If the code was \*just\* reading to/from arrays it'd be millions of times faster. But there \*is\* some overhead in there, so I think 1,000 is more realistic overall.

Answer (score 6):

**First**, as a quick win, I would change

`For Each element In wsText`

into

```
For i = lbound(wsText) to Ubound(wsText)
```

or even better

```
For i = 1 to 10 'or whatever number of items you have there
```

[I have read](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/129931) that looping through an array using a `For each` construct is highly inefficient compared to a `For next` loop.

**Second**, I would replace

```
        service = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, 1).Text
        supplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(4, b).Text
        priceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(2, 1).Text
        price = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element).Cells(a, b).Text
```

by

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(element)
        service = .Cells(a, 1).Text
        supplier = .Cells(4, b).Text
        priceRange = .Cells(2, 1).Text
        price = .Cells(a, b).Text
    End with
```

which is more readable and quicker, since you only set the ref to the worksheet object once.

Comment: Correct. Arrays should be iterated with a `For` loop. It's also on [Docs.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures/8166/for-each-loop#t=201608161416583351664) =)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, unfortunately it still crashes around 7k. (not responding and out of memory).

Comment: @LórántCsabaMihály if you're looking to solve a *specific problem* with your code, you've come to the wrong place. On this site you will receive feedback on all aspects of your **working code**, to improve its efficiency, performance, readability, maintainability, etc. Specific programming issues belong on [so] - note that as it stands your question would probably be closed as *too broad* on SO, because your code isn't narrowed down on the issue; you can't ask SO "here's my code, where's my bug?", that's not how it works. And it's off-topic on Code Review, too.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I asked help on SO and they pointed here. I just need some help to solve this task. The code is working, the problem is that it can't handle big files. If you can code then help and stop saying that this topic is irrelevant.

Comment: @LórántCsabaMihály I will appreciate that you remain civil please. I'm  only telling you what this site is for, and warning you that you may not receive an answer that solves your OOM issue, because fixing bugs is not what we do here, that's Stack Overflow's territory - the only reason your question isn't closed yet is specifically because it appears to work with smaller data sets. Please read [how to get the best value of Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) and our [help/on-topic] to know what we're about. Stack Overflow users don't always know what's OK on CR.